# Как посчитать количество записей в другой таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Привет. Есть три таблицы - сотрудники, отделы, кабинеты. Нужно вывести Id кабинета, его номер, название отдела и количество сотрудников в кабинете.
Структура таблиц такая -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Кабинеты] (
[Id]             INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Номер кабинета] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Номер отдела]   INT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Отделы] (
[Id]              INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Название отдела] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Сотрудники] (
[Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Имя]           NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Фамилия]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Отчество]      NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Дата рождения] DATE           NOT NULL,
[Должность]     INT            NOT NULL,
[Отдел]         INT            NOT NULL,
[Кабинет]       INT            NOT NULL,
[Город]         NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Адрес]         NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[Телефон]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

Так я пытаюсь - это сделать:

```
SELECT r.Id, r.[Номер кабинета], d.[Название отдела], COUNT(c.[Кабинет]) 
FROM Кабинеты AS r 
INNER JOIN Отделы as d ON r.[Номер отдела] = d.[Название отдела] 
INNER JOIN Сотрудники AS c ON  c.[Кабинет] = r.Id
```

Но выходит такая -

> Column 'Кабинеты.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша схема - ошибочна. И даже потенциально противоречива. У Вас сотрудник связан с отделом дважды - напрямую через поле [Сотрудники].[Отдел], и косвенно через [Сотрудники].[Кабинет] - [Кабинеты].[Номер отдела]. И формально ничто не мешает сотрудника отдела 1 посадить в кабинет 2, который закреплён за отделом 3... в такой каше ни в жисть не разобраться.

Поскольку формально в одном кабинете могут сидеть сотрудники нескольких отделов -  прямая однозначная зависимость между кабинетом и отделом отсутствует, следовательно, связь между отделом и кабинетом следует убрать. Т.е. из структуры таблицы [Кабинеты] удалить поле [Номер отдела]. В полях [Отдел] и [Кабинет] таблицы [Сотрудники] следует хранить значения поля [Id] соответствующей таблицы.  Тогда запрос на получение требуемых данных будет выглядеть, например, так:

```
SELECT   [Кабинеты].[Номер кабинета], 
         [Отделы].[Название отдела], 
         COUNT([Сотрудники].[Кабинет]) AS [Количество сотрудников]
FROM     [Кабинеты], 
         [Отделы], 
         [Сотрудники]
WHERE    [Сотрудники].[Кабинет] = [Кабинеты].[Id]
  AND    [Сотрудники].[Отдел]   = [Отделы].[Id]
GROUP BY [Кабинеты].[Номер кабинета], 
         [Отделы].[Название отдела]
```

Ну или так, если кому без слова JOIN жизнь не мила:

```
SELECT     [Кабинеты].[Номер кабинета], 
           [Отделы].[Название отдела], 
           COUNT([Сотрудники].[Кабинет]) AS [Количество сотрудников]
FROM       [Кабинеты]
INNER JOIN [Отделы]     ON [Сотрудники].[Отдел]   = [Отделы].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Сотрудники] ON [Сотрудники].[Кабинет] = [Кабинеты].[Id]
GROUP BY   [Кабинеты].[Номер кабинета], 
           [Отделы].[Название отдела]
```

И последнее. Даже если внести в структуру указанные выше изменения, это не сильно улучшит ситуацию. Например, запросто можно посадить сотрудника в кабинет номер 123, которого в таблице кабинетов просто нет. Или удалить запись об отделе, в котором ещё числятся сотрудники... Для исправления ситуации и исключения такого рода косяков следует в структуру таблицы [Сотрудники] ввести внешние ключи на таблицы [Кабинеты] и [Отделы]. Тогда станет невозможно посадить сотрудника в несуществующий кабинет или отнести к несуществующему отделу, или удалить запись об отделе или кабинете, если за ним числится хотя бы один сотрудник.

Answer (score 1):

У вас идет связывание таблиц по условию

```
r.[Номер отдела] = d.[Название отдела]
```

где

```
r.[Номер отдела] - поле типа INT 

d.[Название отдела] - поле типа NVARCHAR
```

Так нельзя делать, можно привести тип самому с помощью `CAST`, но тогда возможно не будет равенства между этими полями

Поэтому нужно или в таблице отделов создать новое поле с номером отдела или использовать ID в этой таблице как номер отдела.

```
SELECT 
  r.Id, 
  r.[Номер кабинета], 
  d.[Название отдела], 
  COUNT(c.[Кабинет]) 
FROM Кабинеты AS r 
INNER JOIN Отделы as d ON d.[Id] = r.[Номер отдела]
INNER JOIN Сотрудники AS c ON  c.[Кабинет] = r.Id
GROUP BY r.Id, r.[Номер кабинета], d.[Название отдела];
```

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Отдел договорных отношений' to data type int.

Comment: Да. Я понял. Получается конвертировать не получится? Тогда нужно поле создать?

Comment: а как создать поле?